# Why are there gaps in my table? (multirow)

Tags: tables, multirow

I used [www.tablesgenerator.com](http://www.tablesgenerator.com) to create a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|ll|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Event and Phenomena \\ of Interest\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Path}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Frequency}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Raytracing Simulation}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Observations}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Results}} \\ \cline{5-6}
 &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Model} & Citation &  &  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}August 2017 Solar Eclipse:\\ Solar eclipse obscuration\end{tabular} & WWV → WA9VNJ & 10 MHz & \cite{WA9VNJ} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{SAMI3} & \cite{wa9vnj-sami3} & Section \ref{sec:obs_eclipse} & Section \ref{sec:results_eclipse} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}October 2019 Festival of\\ Frequency Measurement:\\ Morning transition\end{tabular} & WWV → WA5FRF & 5 MHz & \cite{wa5frf-ffm-spectrumlab} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{IRI} & \cite{wa5frf-iri-ffm} & Section \ref{sec:obs_ffm} & Section \ref{sec:results_ffm} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}January 2020 Timing Study:\\ Multipath propagation\end{tabular} & WWV → WA5FRF & 5 MHz & \cite{wa5frf-timing} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{IRI} & \cite{wa5frf-iri-jan20} & Section \ref{sec:obs_timing} & Section \ref{sec:results_timing} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{An overview of the datasets and raytracing simulation results used in this paper, and the sections in which they are referenced.}
\label{tab:overview}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

...but there are gaps in the top row:

[image]

How do I get rid of them?

Edit: Wow, these new versions are beautiful. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: I have no problem compiling this except for there is no citation (which is obvious). Maybe other packages have interfaced with the tabular?

Comment: Same here, no white gaps. Try to insert your code into a "pristine" document (I used `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, multirow}
\begin{document}` before your code example.

Comment: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{<table>}` is bad practice as it leads to inconsistent fonts (though this is unlikely the problem you're facing). Consider restructuring your table to fit the textwidth without `\resizebox` (you might use `\small` for instance). Also note that with the default options of the `caption` package a `\caption` inside the `table` environment is formatted to be put *above* the table (hence the bad spacing in your results), either put it above the table or make adjustments to `caption`'s options.

Comment: The code you provided does **not** generate the screenshot you posted. Please fix.

Answer (score 4):

One more suggestion: using `tabularray` package, reduced font size to `\small`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}     % new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}   % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{An overview of the data sets and ray tracing simulation results used in this paper, with the sections in which they are referenced.}
\label{tab:overview}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec  = {@{} X[1.2,l,m,font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont] 
                             X[0.5, c,m] *{6}{l} @{}},
             row{1,2} = {font=\small\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Event and Phenomena of Interest
    &   &   & \SetCell[r=2]{c,f}    {Data\\ set}
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Raytracing Sim.
                    &   &   &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-6}
    & Path 
        & Freq. 
            &   & Model
                    & Citat.%ion 
                        & Observ.%vation 
                            & Results                           \\
    \midrule
August 2017 Solar Eclipse: Solar eclipse obscuration
    & WWV → WA9VNJ 
        & 10 MHz 
            & \cite{WA9VNJ} 
                & SAMI3 
                    & \cite{wa9vnj-sami3}
                        & Sec.~\ref{sec:obs_eclipse} 
                            & Sec.~\ref{sec:results_eclipse}    \\
October 2019 Festival of Frequency Measurement: Morning transition
    & WWV → WA5FRF 
        & 5 MHz 
            & \cite{wa5frf-ffm-spectrumlab} 
                & IRI 
                    & \cite{wa5frf-iri-ffm}
                        & Sec.~\ref{sec:obs_ffm} 
                            & Sec.~\ref{sec:results_ffm}        \\
January 2020 Timing Study: Multipath propagation
    & WWV → WA5FRF 
        & 5 MHz 
            & \cite{wa5frf-timing} 
                & IRI 
                    & \cite{wa5frf-iri-jan20}
                        & Sec.~\ref{sec:obs_timing} 
                            & Sec.~\ref{sec:results_timing} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The table is quite extensive, therefore the columns width is a bit to narrow for nice text formatting in cells. If it is possible to define wider text width, for example width loading

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

in document preamble, the table become more appealing even at use of normal size fonts:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not using `\resizebox`, switching to a `tabualarx` environment, applying sensible abbreviations where possible, getting rid of all vertical lines, loading and using the machinery of the `booktabs` package, not using **boldface** in the header row, and undoing the code clutter inserted by the external software you mention leads to the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow}

%% new:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set paper size and margins as needed
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman clone)
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\smash[b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\hsize} @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\raggedright}X *{7}{l} @{}}
\toprule
\mycell{Event and Phenomena of Interest} 
 & Path & Freq. & Dataset & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Raytracing Sim.} & Obs. & Results \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
 & & & & Model & Cit. &  &  \\ 
\midrule
August 2017 Solar Eclipse: Solar eclipse obscuration 
 & WWV → WA9VNJ & 10 MHz & \cite{WA9VNJ} & SAMI3 & \cite{wa9vnj-sami3}
 & Sec.\ \ref{sec:obs_eclipse} & Sec.\ \ref{sec:results_eclipse} \\ 
\addlinespace
October 2019 Festival of Frequency Measurement: Morning transition
 & WWV → WA5FRF & 5 MHz & \cite{wa5frf-ffm-spectrumlab} & IRI & \cite{wa5frf-iri-ffm}
 & Sec.\ \ref{sec:obs_ffm} & Sec.\ \ref{sec:results_ffm} \\ 
\addlinespace
January 2020 Timing Study: Multipath propagation
 & WWV → WA5FRF & 5 MHz & \cite{wa5frf-timing} & IRI & \cite{wa5frf-iri-jan20}
 & Sec.\ \ref{sec:obs_timing} & Sec.\ \ref{sec:results_timing} \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{An overview of the datasets and raytracing simulation results used in this paper, with the sections in which they are referenced.}
\label{tab:overview}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is similar in spirit to Mico's answer, uses `threeparttable` to reduce some overhead in the table header, and `tabularx` to automatically set the size of the first column. Additionally we set the sizes of the "Path", "Dataset", and "Citation" column to a fixed width to allow line breaking in those.

Depending on the available width of your document you might want to change the fontsize from `\footnotesize` to `\small`, or even remove the switch to get the normal size.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

% column type to get a column of the width of specified text
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NC@rewrite@T[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \sbox0{#1}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@temptokena\expandafter
      {%
        \the\expandafter\@temptokena
        \expandafter p\expandafter{\the\wd0}%
      }%
    \NC@find
  }
\makeatother

% shortcut to get left aligned p, X, etc.
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}}

\newcommand*\mcell[2][t]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \tabcolsep=.5\tabcolsep
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption
      {%
        An overview of the datasets and raytracing simulation results used in
        this paper, and the sections in which they are referenced%
        \label{tab:overview}%
      }
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
      { @{} LX LT{WA9VNJ} S LT{Dataset} l LT{Citation\tnote{a}} c c @{} }
      \toprule
      Event and Phenomena of Interest
        & Path & {\mcell{Frequency\\in \unit{\mega\hertz}}} & Dataset
        & Model\tnote{a} & Citation\tnote{a} & \mcell{Obser-\\vations\tnote{b}}
        & Results\tnote{b} \\
      \midrule
      August 2017 Solar Eclipse: Solar eclipse obscuration
        & WWV $\rightarrow$ WA9VNJ & 10 & \cite{WA9VNJ}
        & SAMI3 & \cite{wa9vnj-sami3} & \ref{sec:obs_eclipse}
        & \ref{sec:results_eclipse} \\
      \addlinespace
      October 2019 Festival of Frequency Measurement: Morning transition
        & WWV $\rightarrow$ WA5FRF & 5 & \cite{wa5frf-ffm-spectrumlab}
        & IRI & \cite{wa5frf-iri-ffm} & \ref{sec:obs_ffm}
        & \ref{sec:results_ffm} \\
      \addlinespace
      January 2020 Timing Study: Multipath propagation
        & WWV $\rightarrow$ WA5FRF & 5 & \cite{wa5frf-timing}
        & IRI & \cite{wa5frf-iri-jan20} & \ref{sec:obs_timing}
        & \ref{sec:results_timing} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a] of raytracing simulation
      \item[b] section in this paper
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result (I manually entered the data of your references to get this image):

[image]